# Solve $b_1 e^{-a_1x^2}-b_2 e^{-a_2x^2}-b_3 e^{-a_3x^2}=0, \forall x$

Tags: exponential-function, systems-of-equations, exponential-sum

Suppose,
\begin{align*}
b_1 e^{-a_1x^2}-b_2 e^{-a_2x^2}-b_3 e^{-a_3x^2}=0, \forall x
\end{align*}
Assume $a_1,a_2,a_3, b_1,b_2, b_3>0$

What are the possible values of $a_1,a_2,a_3, b_1,b_2, b_3>0$ that satisfy this equation?

One solution is:
\begin{align*}
b_1=b_2+b_3\\
a_1=a_2=a_3
\end{align*}

Is this a unique solution? Or is there other solutions?

Comment: evaluate the expression for well chosen $x$ (e.g. $x=0,1,2$)

Comment: Would that prove uniqueness of the my solution?

Comment: for example $x=0$ implies $b_1=b_2+b_3$, then you can play around with the equation $ b_2(e^{-a_1x^2}-e^{-a_2x^2})+b_3(e^{-a_1x^2}-e^{-a_3x^2})=0$ to show that $a_1=a_2=a_3$.

Comment: Oh. I see. Thanks. I get. Thanks a lot